# Query to Search Dates and notes inside a MySQL Column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Here is my case
I have got a column(notes) in table having   as shown below.Some of the table schema

```
`Priority` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`Phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`Status` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`Notes` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
```

**Record 1 in notes Column**

```
Sunday, June 01, 2017 6:57:39 PM : First Note
Sunday, June 02, 2017 6:55:59 PM : 2nd Note
Sunday, June 03, 2017 6:52:52 PM : new notes1
Sunday, June 11, 2017 6:55:55 PM : Third Type Note Sunday, June 11, 2017 6:55:59 Status: Closed

Sunday, June 12, 2017 6:57:33 PM : new notes2
Sunday, June 13, 2017 6:57:39 PM Status: Changed
```

**Record 2**

```
Sunday, June 01, 2017 6:57:39 PM : First Cake baked
Sunday, June 02, 2017 6:55:59 PM : 2nd  Cake baked
Sunday, June 03, 2017 6:52:52 PM : new Cake type
Sunday, June 11, 2017 6:55:55 PM : updated Cakes Sunday, June 11, 2017 6:55:59 Status: Closed

Sunday, June 12, 2017 6:57:33 PM : back to home
Sunday, June 13, 2017 6:57:39 PM Status: Changed
```

I have to search inside these records using Dates.

Say if date range is **Jun 03 to Jun 12** then all records having dates and there corresponding text should return. Something like below

```
Priority | Phone | Status | Notes
*****      *****   *****    Sunday, June 03, 2017 6:52:52 PM : new notes1
*****      *****   *****    *****
*****      *****   *****    Sunday, June 12, 2017 6:52:52 PM : new notes2
*****      *****   *****    Sunday, June 03, 2017 6:52:52 PM : new Cake type
*****      *****   *****    *****
*****      *****   *****    Sunday, June 12, 2017 6:52:52 PM : back to home
```

Comment: It seems a very wrong schema that leads to very inefficient code solutions. If you plan to search on those values then use separated columns in a related table to store them.

Comment: @Steve Agreed, But user already have data and I just have to query the report.

Comment: Perhaps it is better to make a script that takes these _Notes_ split them and writes the required table to make decent queries. You can run these scripts once a day (or differently according to your user needs), mark the rows that have been translated and go on. After the first run you could get good response time (if the incoming data is not too big)

Comment: Bad databases ask for bad solutions. Don't use SQL to solve this. Write a program; read all records (`select * from badtable`); use a loop to read the note lines for every record; detect the desired lines and show them.